# initialization of a field inside an anonymous union, upon declaration

Tags: c, struct, initialization, unions, anonymous

I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct cxt_simple_socket_address_s
{
        int is_ipv6;
        cs_inaddr_t ip;
        unsigned short ip_port;
} cxt_simple_socket_address_t;

typedef struct cs_inaddr
{
        union {
            struct in6_addr in6;
            struct
            {
                uint8_t pad[12];
                uint32_t in;
            };
            long long as_longs[2];
        };
} cs_inaddr_t;
```

I would like to initialize a struct of type  cxt_simple_socket_address_t upon declaration:

```
cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {.in = INADDR_ANY};
```

This line doesn't compile. I have tried countless other variations, but I believe my problem is than .in is found within an anonymous struct inside an anonymous union.

HELP?

Comment: You should reference `in` heirarchically. It should be like this: `cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {.ip = {.<UNION NAME> = {.<STRUCT NAME> = {.in = INADDR_ANY}}}};`

Comment: But both union and struct are nameless

Answer (score 1):

Firstly order of declaration is wrong.
`struct cs_inaddr` should be declared first, followed by `struct cxt_simple_socket_address_s`.
Since its is nested Structure (compiler will look for definition of `cs_inaddr` first).

```
typedef struct cs_inaddr
{
    union {
        struct in6_addr in6;
        struct
        {
            unsigned char pad[12];
            unsigned int in;
        };
        long long as_longs[2];
    };
} cs_inaddr_t;

typedef struct cxt_simple_socket_address_s
{
    int is_ipv6;
    cs_inaddr_t ip;
    unsigned short ip_port;
} cxt_simple_socket_address_t;
```

Initialization of variable should be as:

```
cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {.ip = {.in = INADDR_ANY}};
```

Tested it using the below:

```
cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {.ip = {.in = 100}};
printf("%d\n", any.ip.in);
```

Output: `100`

**Note**:
The nested (inner) structure can be anonymous, since the outer structure has a *tag* name.
Hence can be accessed.

Comment: Youn don't need such thing, `cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {.ip.in = INADDR_ANY};` is enough: http://ideone.com/zB7UJG

Comment: Either way it works, IMO `any = {.ip = {.in = INADDR_ANY }};` is more descriptive.

Comment: still doesn't work for me. maybe due to compilation differences

Comment: What is the compilation error you are getting ? I compiled using `gcc FileName.c`.

Answer (score 0):

`cxt_simple_socket_address_s` doesn't contain any field naming `in`. Are you mean

```
cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {ip.in = INADDR_ANY};
```

?

Comment: Once any is declared I can write: any.ip.in = INADDR_ANY and it compiled fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to move the whole declaration of `struct cs_inaddr` before `cxt_simple_socket_address_t` in order to make it visible.

Then initialize using:

```
cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {.ip.in = INADDR_ANY};
```

Also note that anonymous unions are introduced in `C11` or as a `gcc` extension.

Comment: The structs order is not as it is in real code of course. it was just for you to understand the structure of the struct I am trying to initialize. I am compiling with gcc

Comment: Then `cxt_simple_socket_address_t any = {.ip.in = INADDR_ANY};` will work as expected.

Comment: Well it doesn't. I get the following error:                     error: unknown field âinâ specified in initializer
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
src/simple_socket_tcp_async.c:344: error: missing braces around initializer
src/simple_socket_tcp_async.c:344: error: (near initialization for âany.ip.<anonymous>â)